# How do you extract POST parameter in node.js?

Tags: node.js, drupal-7

I was trying to send data from Drupal page to node

Drupal code

```
function sample_submit($form, &$form_state) { //Function to connect with node and save into Mongo using node
  $jsonData = check_plain($form_state['values']['jsonData']);
  $request_url = "http://10.20.5.112:3000/save";
  $options = array(
                'method' => 'POST',
                'data' => $jsonData,
                'timeout' => 15,
                'headers' => array('Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'),
        );
    $result = drupal_http_request($request_url, $options);
}
```

Node.Js

```
app.post('/save', function(req, res){  //Rest Api Function to get data from pushed by drupal
  //console.log(req.data);
  res.send('Success');
});
```

How to get the data send from drupal as jsondata  in the node.js

Comment: Are you using expressjs framework?

Comment: yes I am using Express

Comment: Are you sure you are using `express.bodyparser` ? You need that to be able to access POST ed parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the posted data from req.body, for example `console.log(req.body);`
http://expressjs.com/api.html#req.body

or you can use req.param, for example `console.log(req.param('data'));`
http://expressjs.com/api.html#req.param

Comment: Both are not working. body gives me 'undefined' and my params is []

Comment: Try to change the content type of your post to: application/json

Comment: I see here https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_http_request/7 that the data needs to be formatted like this for example:  'param=value&param=value&...'. How is the $jsonData formatted?

Comment: even if it is just a string. how to retrive is my issue.

Comment: if you console.log(req) can you see your posted data there?

Comment: Are you using bodyParser() middleware in your express settings?